# Disadvantages of hidden iFrames in file upload

Tags: security, iframe, upload, hidden

I'm uploading a file to my server by setting my form target to an invisible iFrame on the page. The iFrame is created and dropped(by setting a timeout) in the upload button click handler itself.

Is there any reason why I shouldn't use an iFrame? I ask coz I've heard only bad things about iFrames. I love the way it makes the whole upload process look by not reloading the page.

So is there any security issues i should be worried about?

Thanks,

Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

IFrames are used for XSS (Cross Site Scripting) attacks.

See:

http://www.computeruser.com/tutorials/iframe-injection-attack-is-most-common-and-most-basic-cross-site-scripting-xss-attacks.html

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross_Frame_Scripting

Comment: What i gather from both these articles is that iFrames can be used "intentionally" by someone wanting to cause harm but my question is that by using an iFrame in my page am i exposing any threat. I looked it up alot and am pretty convinced that an iFrame can be used without worrying too much. (Read Last comment in http://www.thespanner.co.uk/2007/10/24/iframes-security-summary/)

Comment: Google uses iframes with their google_conversion_frame. Alas, I don't know any specifics about possible security holes.